# Why is my connection rejected in one solution but not in another solution while using the same Type Provider?

Tags: .net, f#, webserver, type-providers

I have two different mobile app solutions that attempt to parse a Json file on a webserver.

One solution retrieves the json without any issues.

The other solution throws the following exception:

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection refused

Here's the code that's used in both solutions:

```
open FSharp.Data

[<Literal>]
let JsonPath = "https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json"

type Car = { Title:string ; ReleaseYear:int }

type MovieProvider = JsonProvider<JsonPath>

let getCars() =

    async {
      let! result = MovieProvider.AsyncLoad JsonPath
      return result.Movies 
             |> Array.toList
             |> List.map (fun m -> { Title=m.Title; ReleaseYear=m.ReleaseYear }) 
    }
```

Both projects per solution are *Portable Class Libraries*.

1. I have reviewed the Android Manifest and have not observed any difference. Hence, neither of the manifest files per solution have permissions set.
2. I have tried running the failed solution as an Admin

Why can I retrieve Json from a webserver in one solution but not the other solution **on my machine** when I'm using the same *type provider* to retrieve the json?

Comment: Is the Type Provider trusted in VS?

Comment: @Asti Didn't that whole thing go away with VS 2015?

Comment: @TeaDrivenDev Yes.